# Controling Robotics locomotives using android and GPS

Tags: android, gps, controls, robotics

The project objective is something like this:

We would have a locomotive robot having on-board GPS on it.
Now using that GPS we want to track the position of robot and trace it on android cellphone.
(as they provide best interface with Google services)

Not only that

We even want to control the robot from android cellphone.
Is it possible to send control signal from android cellphone to that robot so that robot can make a move according to control signal.

How can we make a connection between android cellphone and on-board GPS of robot.
(We are somewhat newbie to robotics)

Any better ideas, suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Dension Wirc module:

[WiRC module by Dension](http://wirc.dension.com/)
It works for RC controlled platforms by sending a pulse width modulated train, allowing you to control servos and electronic speed controllers. There are 8 channels. I'm using it to control 2 tracks and a pan/tilt turret, **it works great.** I emailed the support team, and they sent me an iPhone project, which got me running in a matter of hours. The WiRC kit comes with a camera, so I can drive my robot remotely via wifi.

In terms of GPS, I did a test on iPhone, under clear sky, and the GPS signal drifts badly. The accuracy is indeed somewhere between 30-50 feet, it is not enough to track position of a small robot precisely. I will post a screenshot of my experiment.

Check out this screenshot: I'm walking along the white paths on the map with the phone in my shirt pocket. Every second it places a pin on the map. You can see how badly the red pins deviate from the white path. This is 30-50 feet off path. For a 2 feet long robot, this is a major trouble. If it tries to correct it's path with such resolution of GPS, it is likely to become very confused.
[image: GPS experiment]

I've seen a differential drive equation on wikipedia (a motor with slit encoders), counting the number of slits that passed past encoder in a certain interval of time. This may help correct the GPS, but requires additional hardware

Comment: Awesome work  !! But i heard in android we cannot find exact current location of cellphone as it always return position of tower and not actual cellphone.
I may have heard wrong thing but still how is it possible to track current live location of cellphone using GPS.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on something same like this 
I am trying to make an autonomous robot capable of moving itself based on some extensive robotics algorithms but certainly you don't need that.

But I think it will be  better for you to mount the Android phone on the Robot and then control it with your laptop via WiFi or any other medium.

Mounting an android phone will have many advantages like:

1. Having a nice GPS and where there is no  need to  do extra work to integrate it with other hardware and software.
2. And you can have other hardware like accelerometer, proximity sensor, gravity sensor etc. which can be useful in many ways.

Now there is a lot of data for making Robots based on Android.  Here is the [Cellbots](http://www.cellbots.com)
they work on making robots from android  and control them remotely from laptops or Android.

Comment: I have the same idea! Mounting a phone on a robot is a good way to go. There's a possibility o doing inertial navigation at some point in the future. iPhone and Android proximity sensor is practically an on/off switch to detect if a device is facing up or down on a table. It's not enough for robotic purposes

Comment: @Alex-Stone I  am using  arduino with Android and planning to  add some additional sensors because android is not enough for all robotics purposes.                                                              what i am trying to  get from android is (1)Using its GPS and Accelerometer (2) Getting a live video feed from its camera to my PC

Comment: Thee variation of GPS location is also a problem but i m trying to solve it with a localization algorithm like Particle Filter or Markov localization